# Change position for div element using JQuery if it is not visible in viewport

Tags: jquery, css, position, element

I am having a vertical menu in left side of the screen/browser with its corresponding sub-menu items. I am stuck at a place.
**The requirement is :**
MouseHover over an element, if the sub-menu is visible inside the viewport (i.e. the visible and accessible window area) then do nothing; but, if it extends beyond the visible area then the sub-menu should populate towards the top of the window.
That means the sub-menu should be visible within the viewport (if it hides downside it should open towards top).

Thanks

Comment: Please provide us some code example.

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/G7qfq/5/ 
But, it should be for top bottom.
That means, as in this case the menu is working for right and left viewport. I need this for top and bottom thing.
I hope it might help out. Since, I am not able to access the machine (server is not accessible as the VPN works only from 22:00 Hrs IST to 06:00 HRS IST. :(

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

## http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

this is a very simple jQuery plug in that programs a logic to know when an element enters the viewport, as well as many other conditional logic viewport based calls.

all you need to do once everything is loaded in:

```
$(window).scroll (function(){

if  ($('.menu') .is(":in-viewport")){
 
 // Do literally anything you want with jQuery   
}

});
```

Very powerful plug in.

Comment: Hi Justin,
Thanks for your support. But unfortunately, this didn't worked as per my requirement.
However, I tried my efforts and finally I got a solution. Here it is in my next comment. :)
Somehow it seems that it is not working in IE8 and IE7.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".mainNav > li").hover(
        function(){
            var winHt = $(window).height(); 
            var scrHt = $(document).height();

            var viewport = {};
            viewport.top = $(window).scrollTop();
            viewport.bottom = viewport.top + $(window).height();

            var bounds = {};
            bounds.top = $(".sub_menu",this).offset().top;
            bounds.bottom = bounds.top + $(".sub_menu",this).outerHeight();

            if(viewport.bottom < bounds.bottom){ 
                var ScrTop = parseInt(bounds.bottom-viewport.bottom);
                $(".sub_menu",this).css("marginTop","-"+ScrTop+"px");
            }else{}
        },
        function(){
            $(".sub_menu",this).css("marginTop","0px");
    });
```

Comment: Here, "mainNav" is the parent <ul> class which has many <li> items.
Each <li> item has a variety of sub-menus which comes inside a class named as "sub_menu".
That's all.
Now why it is not working in IE8 and below, this is under my research.